# Why $this->load->model returns null?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

Module name = simple_checkout. 
Admin controller path - admin/controller/extension/module. 
Controller classname - ControllerExtensionModuleSimpleCheckout. 
Admin model path - admin/model/extension/module. 
Model classname - ModelExtensionModuleSimpleCheckout.

```
$this->load->model('setting/setting'); // returns null.
$this->load->model('extension/module/simple_checkout'); // returns null
```

Why ALL load->model in admin controller file return null?

Comment: $this->load->model('extension/module/simple_checkout'); this will not return anything, you have to use innner function of that file like test(), you can use it by $this->model_extension_module_simple_checkou->test();

Comment: As prashant told, $this->load->model('extension/module/simple_checkout'); only allows to load the model files . to access your model function $this->model_extension_module_simple_checkou->test();  if you have doubt, please have look at default extenison so you can learn how to create modules